# Issue with Loading Images on Vercel

Tags: html, tailwind-css, vercel, host, astrojs

I'm encountering a peculiar problem when trying to load images on my landing page hosted on Vercel. Locally, the images display correctly, as shown in the image below:

[image]

However, when deploying to Vercel, the images are not being found. I am using two different paths for the images, both in the *tailwind.config.mjs* file and the *Header.astro* file.

**tailwind.config.mjs File:**

```
backgroundImage: {
    'bg-header': "url('./public/img/header/REHeader.jpg')"
},
```

**Header.astro File:**

```
<img
    src="../../public/img/header/RE2logo.png"
    class="h-12 w-24"
    alt="Resident Evil Logo"
/>
```

The final result of my deployment, with the images not loading, [can be seen here.](https://resident-evil-2-landingpage.vercel.app/)

The GitHub repository c[an be accessed here!](https://github.com/moraesWesley/resident-evil-2-landingpage)

**Note: I am using the Astro framework!**

Could someone help me understand why the images are not loading after deploying to Vercel? I appreciate any guidance or solutions to this issue.

Comment: It might be worth adding your project structure and any build configurations as it's likely that your picture is being moved to a different folder (although I believe Astro doesn't change the public directory).

Comment: Reading the astro documentation it seems the files will be copied into your build folder, which probably means that the public/ directory doesn't exist anymore https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/project-structure/#:~:text=The%20files%20in%20this%20folder%20will%20be%20copied%20into%20the%20build%20folder%20untouched%2C%20and%20then%20your%20site%20will%20be%20built.

Comment: @rishi So, please, what should I do? Should I move my files into the src directory?

Comment: You should be able to access those files directly from the root of your project i.e. `./img/header/REHeader.jpg`. See if that works

Comment: Hello @rishi , after many attempts my way, it worked your way! But I still have questions about the route path! Can you please respond with a comprehensive answer so I can give my vote to your response? And thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi @Wesley as requested, I have added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, I'm adding an answer with a few details

Let's say you have the following project structure, (taken from astro [documentaion](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/project-structure/#:%7E:text=The%20files%20in%20this%20folder%20will%20be%20copied%20into%20the%20build%20folder%20untouched%2C%20and%20then%20your%20site%20will%20be%20built))

```
├── public/
│   ├── robots.txt
│   ├── favicon.svg
│   └── social-image.png
├── src/
│   └── ...
├── astro.config.mjs
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

All of your code that lives in the src folder gets optimised and compiled whereas astro (like many/most tools out there, won't touch your public folder and any assets that it might contain)
Usually, you'd want to put any images/assets in your src folder, however if you don't want the compiler to process any files, you put them in your public folder.

After you build your project, astro will create something like below

```
├── _astro/
│   └── ...
├── index.html
├── robots.txt
└── social-image.png
```

Notice that everything inside your `public` folder has been dumped into the root of your project alongside the index.html page.

Furthermore, in your case, since you have created a folder inside the public directory, astro will retain that and copy the folder as-is in your project root.

I would recommend running your build command on your local machine to examine the project structure after astro compiles everything.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! Now I understand that it's not about Vercel, but indeed, about the directory structure when building with Astro! In fact, when I investigate the images locally, there is no 'public' folder! That explains a lot!
Again, truly grateful for your humility!